# using data validation for copying a named chart form another worksheet

Tags: vba, select

I have been working on a dashboard where I can use drop-down lists to select and copy/paste named charts with the same name from other sheets in the entire workbook.

I'm trying a few things but none works:

```
Activeworkbook.ChartObjects Range("F2").activate
```

F2 being the cell with data validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your select isn't working because you need to use the value in your cell as a string referring to the chartobject in the collection. Change the sheet reference below as needed. I have my cell containing the name of the chartobject and the chartobject itself on the same sheet but it sounds like that's different than your setup.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")).Activate`

Which you could then shorten if you have workbook and worksheet variables referring to `ThisWorkbook`, your worksheet with your chartobject, and your worksheet with your data-validated name cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that! It solves the first part of the question, namely using the value in the cell as reference.

The second part is more tricky: I have several sheets with named charts in the workbook and I need the command to copy a particular named chart in the entire workbook.

One option is just to put all my charts into a single worksheet. but ideally I would like to keep them in their respective sheets.

Any way this could work?

Comment: You should post this as a new question for proper visibility. Right now this is an answer to an already-answered question. Until then, just know that the chartobjects group belongs to an individual sheet. You'll need the sheet and the chartobject name to point to a specific chartobject within a workbook. I can help more if you post a new question with details.